# Viewing token contract address in mist wallet

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, tokens, wallets, mist

**My question:**

How do I view the `Contract address` of a token in the mist wallet?

---

**Elaborating:**

Lets say I deploy a new token on the mist wallet. The Token is then visible in the account that I used to deploy it with the amount of tokens associated with that account. Though I don't see an option that shows me that new tokens `Contract address`

On **etherscan.io**, you can query tokens by the `Contract address`:

[image]

https://etherscan.io/token/Qtum

I'm not sure if there is an interface option in the mist wallet *(preferable)* or if geth has to be used directly or something else, and what the command might be in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mist (top right of the screen) there a link to "Contracts". If you deployed the contract using mist, the contract will appear there. Click on it and you will see all the information, including the contract address.

If you did not deployed using mist, you can "watch the contract", (in the same window). It will ask you for the ABI and the contract name, then you will see the contract and clicking on it give you all the information.

Hope this helps.